# Users are unable to login to my OSX server as themselves

Tags: mac, osx-el-capitan, osx-server

I run an OSX server and have around 15 end users, about 4 of them are unable to login to my server as themselves, so as a work around I've created a user that has limited administrative access to the server. However, this is obviously not a good work around.

The error that happens when the end user tries to connect is;

```
You do not have permission to access SERVER as USER # or something along those lines
```

Or

```
There was a problem connecting to the server “SERVER”.
```

I've checked my sharing preferences on the server, edited it so that anyone on my network can access it, however it seems to still happen. It may be worth mentioning that the users that seem to be having the problems are on a mix of laptops and iMacs. Does anybody have an idea that I may have overlooked in order to resolve this issue?

My OSX specifics, OSX El capitan v10.11.6

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out a way to fix this, why it works I have no idea, but it works.

On the users system do:

```
sudo rm ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist
```

Fixes the problem and allows the user to login to the server as themselves